# How to get specific values from my data based on an array values using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data array to which I have inserted a column with values starting from 0. So now my data contains all float values.

After some processing I have a array ARR which contains values from my 1st column. Using these ARR values (or positions) I want to extract the remaining columns to a new array using Numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import io
data =io.StringIO("""
ID,1,2,3
5362,0.97,-0.40,-0.76
485,-0.65,0.53,0.62
582,0.04,0.99,0.76
99,0.77,0.53,0.39
75,-0.44,0.52,0.85
474,0.35,0.8,0.13
594,-0.29,0.03,0.74
597,0.96,-0.35,0.59
124,0.73,0.61,0.76
635,0.88,0.96,-0.98
7894,-0.04,0.04,0.52
1268,0.56,0.73,-0.37
38,0.46,0.62,0.73
88,0.02,0.16,0.098
887,0.46,0.65,-0.89
""")

data = np.genfromtxt(data, delimiter=',', skip_header=2, dtype=np.float64)
index = np.arange(data.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)
data = np.hstack([index, data])


ARR = [[1.],[2.],[4.],[6.],[7.],[9.]]
```

Expected Output Like:

I want all the row values at the positions indicated in the `ARR`. I can also show it as Integer values. I want all the rows at these positions in my data array.

```
485,-0.65,0.53,0.62
582,0.04,0.99,0.76
75,-0.44,0.52,0.85
594,-0.29,0.03,0.74
597,0.96,-0.35,0.59
635,0.88,0.96,-0.98
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to do the following (no need to add an index column to the data). Also, I do not understand why you specify the row numbers as floats (`1., 2., 4.,...`). Your row numbers must be integers. The solution here corrects this aspect.

```py
# np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
data = np.genfromtxt(data, delimiter=',', skip_header=2, dtype=np.float64)
ARR = [[1.],[2.],[4.],[6.],[7.],[9.]]
ARR = np.array(ARR).astype(int).flatten()
data[ARR, :]
```

**Output**:

```
array([[485.  ,  -0.65,   0.53,   0.62],
       [582.  ,   0.04,   0.99,   0.76],
       [ 75.  ,  -0.44,   0.52,   0.85],
       [594.  ,  -0.29,   0.03,   0.74],
       [597.  ,   0.96,  -0.35,   0.59],
       [635.  ,   0.88,   0.96,  -0.98]])
```

> **Optionally**:
>   In case you must add the `index`, then use the following code block in addition to the code you posted in the question.

```py
ARR = np.array(ARR).astype(int).flatten()
data[ARR, 1:]
```

Comment: Yes. I needed the locations initially but the array was taking float values, but this solution solved it as I needed the index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Using the way *data* is shaped, you can easily do:

```
for value in ARR:
    print(data[int(value[0])][1::])
```

Hope it helps!

Edit: Added [1::] to slice the result and remove the index position.

Comment: If I assign it to a variable ```new_arr = data[int(value[0])][1::]```, and try to save it to csv, I am getting different values. If I do not assign, it is working fine. Also the other solution provided works.

Comment: I don't know how you're saving to a csv, but you might have to add a newline character between lines as you save them. Regardless, glad you found a working solution!